# How to set file path to src folder of project

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I want to make a program that you can email to someone and they can run it.
Right now my code for making a file is like this:

```
File f = new File("/Users/S0urceC0ded/Desktop/Code/project/JavaStuffs/src/axmlfile.xml);
f.createNewFile();
```

But what if someones username is not S0urceC0ded, or they put the project in a different place? How could I set the file path to the src folder plus the filename?

Comment: Either put those files on the classpath or decide on a path that will be the same for each machine `/home/root/projects/...` or `C:/workspace/...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the path off entirely, it will use the directory of the project.
Change

```
File f = new File("/Users/S0urceC0ded/Desktop/Code/project/JavaStuffs/src/axmlfile.xml");
```

To

```
File f = new File("axmlfile.xml");
```

Comment: Your answer will **not** save the `file` to the `src` folder. However, it is probably the right solution to his problem.

Comment: Mike is right. I found the solution off of that("src/anxmlfile.xml")

Comment: File is not created if i use `("src/filename.htm")` How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I generally use code like this for temporary file storage, this way it gets  cleaned up when the application finishes.  If required you can allow the user to save a version of the file or move it to a permanent location.

```
try{
   //create a temporary file
   File temp = File.createTempFile("axmlfile", ".xml"); 
   System.out.println("Location: " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
}catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```